# I have a painting I need translated as in who the artist is

Tags: character-identification

[image: a watercolor floral painting original with a red seal mark or signature mark]**

1. Artwork painting translation to English artist identification

**

Comment: art name is 牵牛(morning glory flower, Convolvulaceae)， artist's seal is 朱慧

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name of the art is ***The Morning Glories***, drawn by an artist called "ZhuHui".